# using locals in Django views and global variables can be referenced in templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am working on a existing code base and saw this piece of code:

```
from constants import AppType
"""
AppType is a constant class in constants.py and it goes like
AppType:
    TypeA = 1
    TypeB = 2
"""
@log_request(log_response=False)
@user_profile_required
def app_home(request, user, user_profile):
    apps = db_manager.get_all_apps_for_user(
        user_profile.uid, user_profile.platform
    )
    return render(request, 'appinfo/all_apps.html', locals())
    # notice the use of locals here for convinience
```

In `all_apps.html`:

```
{% for val, name in app_types.items %}
{{val}}, {{name}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

and I see this response when rendered out:

```
1, TypeA
2, TypeB
```

According to my understanding(correct me if I am wrong), `locals` is supposed to return a dict of local variables. But clearly there is no `app_types` in the view function.

I suspect there is some magic that translated `AppType` to `app_types` and I appended `TypeC = 3` to `AppType`. Then I indeed saw `3, TypeC` rendered out. So it seems that my suspect turned out to be true?

What is the trick here or am I missing some other information for understanding this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out definition of `app_types` are in `context_processors.py` and loaded into `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in `settings.py`.

So this is just problem with understanding of Django template system and its processing